# Html tag in the string not working in browser

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display some information coming from the database. Database field takes the input from the ck-editor and save the HTML as a string.

[image]

Now when I am trying to display those data it comes like as the blue section in the above image. But I want it as the red section.

```
 echo "Product Name : Personal Loan<span><br>Loan Range :<br>Minimum : 50000<br>Maximum : 2000000<br>Loan Repayment Tenure :<br>Minimum 1 Year<br>Maximum 5 Years</span><br>";
```

When I use this code the red block section of the above image is showing

but when I use

```
echo $infos['Loan']['addtional_features'];
```

the blue section is showing. that is, the all string with the tag is displaying.

What could be the reason?

Comment: how are you rendering your view ?

Comment: just in the browser.

Comment: It is possible that you are escaping the string before rendering

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `print_r($infos['Loan']['addtional_features']);`?

Comment: print_r($infos['Loan']['addtional_features']) is displaying the  below result


Product Name : Personal Loan<span><br>Loan Range :<br>Minimum : 50000<br>Maximum : 2000000<br>Loan Repayment Tenure :<br>Minimum 1 Year<br>Maximum 5 Years</span><br>1

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the string stored is HTML-encoded twice (e.g. `&lt;br&gt;`, instead of `<br>`). Try to [`html_entity_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) your string, before to write it in the output.

Comment: Thanks. It works.

but here i am direct fetching the value from the database. There is no "encoded" happens...